# Show Confirmation Message Yes or No in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have drop-down box where users can select Yes or No, if user selects Yes from the drop-down then i want to show a confirmation box that shows Yes or No option.  If only user selects Yes in the confirmation box then i want to proceed calling my other function which makes an update to the backend database. If user selects No in the confirmation box then i don't want to proceed and cancel the operation.  Here is my drop-down code:

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckDropDownSelection"
                        runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="16px">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="-- Please Selet --" Value="-- Please Selet --"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="YES"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="NO"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
```

here is my code behind:

```
protected void CheckDropDownSelection(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (ddl_CloseTask.SelectedValue == "YES")
        {
            CloseTask();
        }
        else
        { 

        }

    }

    protected void CloseTask()
    { 

        // here is where i close the task

    }
```

Comment: And where is a problem with it?

Comment: before i call the CloseTask, i want to show the confirmation box if the user select yes from the confirmation box then i want to proceed calling the the CloseTrack method else don't do anything.  thanks

Comment: This can be accomplished in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391979/how-to-show-a-message-box-in-an-asp-net-page

Comment: drop-down does not have onClick properties..

Comment: is that helpful to you ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has too many Yes/No. I hope it won't confuse to user -

If a user selects **YES** in **DropDownList**, a **Confirmation Message** will be prompted.

If the user selects **YES** in **Confirmation Message**, **DropDownList** will post back to server.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_CloseTask" Width="157px" 
   AutoPostBack="true" 
   OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckDropDownSelection"
   runat="server" 
   AppendDataBoundItems="true" Height="16px">
   <asp:ListItem Text="-- Please Selet --" Value="-- Please Selet --"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="YES"></asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="NO"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectlistId = '<%= ddl_CloseTask.ClientID %>',
        selectlist = document.getElementById(selectlistId);

    selectlist.onchange = function() {
        if (selectlist.options[selectlist.selectedIndex].value == "YES") {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?")) {
                __doPostBack(selectlistId, '');
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8697129/296861).

### Updated:

If the user selects **NO** from the **Confirmation Box**, set **DropDownList** value to the first value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectlistId = '<%= ddl_CloseTask.ClientID %>',
        selectlist = document.getElementById(selectlistId);

    selectlist.onchange = function() {
        if (selectlist.options[selectlist.selectedIndex].value == "YES") {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to do this?")) {
                __doPostBack(selectlistId, '');
            } else {
                // User selected NO, so change DropDownList back to 0.
                selectlist.selectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Win, one last question, if the user selects NO from the confirmation box, can i set the drop-selected value to the first value like ddl_CloseTask.selectedindex = 0? how can i do this from the javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

Read my full post regarding same : [Calling Server Side function from Client Side Script](http://pranayamr.blogspot.no/2012/01/calling-server-side-function-from.html)

This is how you can achieve with sever and client side code

attach event of client code mostly in page_load

```
yourDropDownList.Attributes["onChange"] = "jsFunction(this);";
```

Client script

```
function jsFunction(mlist){
  var myselect = mlist;
  if(myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].value == "YES")
  {
    if(confirm("Delete item!"))
    {
      $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
         url: window.location.pathname + "/CloseTask";,
           data: dataString,
          contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
         error:
                  function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                         $(errorlableid).show();
                         $(errorlableid).html("Error");
                  },
         success:
             function(result) {

                }
         }
         }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

serverside code

```
[WebMethod]
protected void CloseTask()
{
    //code to close task

}
```

Comment: thanks, i have tried the code but getting this error: expected expression is missing and also , is missing so i can't run it. Please not i am using asp.net.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

You would want to prompt the user on the "onchange" event of your DropDownList control. You can add the call to your javascript function in the aspx markup or in the code behind. (I used the code behind in this case).

So, your code behind would look something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    ddl_CloseTask.Attributes.Add("onchange", "return validate(this);");
}

protected void CheckDropDownSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddl_CloseTask.SelectedValue == "YES")
    {
        CloseTask();
    }
    else
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}

private void CloseTask()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

And your aspx markup would look something like this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_CloseTask" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="CheckDropDownSelection">
    <asp:ListItem Text="-- Please Select --" Value="-- Please Select --" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="YES" Value="YES" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="NO" Value="NO" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(ddl) {
        var selected = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;

        if (selected == 'YES' && !confirm('Close the task?')) {
            return false;
        }

        __doPostBack(ddl.id, '');
    }
</script>
```